# Wildcard CORS with allowcredentials true

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel, cors

I have a project where I'm using wildcard subdomains like `user.mysite.com` where username is a wildcard.

In my server (PHP) I've set the following headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

This allows me to do ajax calls from the frontend since I don't know what the domain is going to be. However I also need my cookies to be sent with the requests for maintaining sessions but when I tell AngularJS on my frontend to send the credentials I get the following message:

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true
```

I understand this is for security reasons but now I have no way of session management in my app. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Where I tell Angular to send credentials:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

My ajax requests are being send to a different subdomain. ie the url could be `billy.mysite.com` but the ajax requests are being sent to `api.mysite.com`.

Comment: Just fetch the host of the current request and use that instead of the wildcard

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! Thanks @PeeHaa

Answer (score 5):

@iamjonesy - You have done silly mistake.

```
"A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true"
```

To avoid the above error just follow the steps.
Suppose your api server is **http://api.com** . And your UI server, from where you executing ajax call, is **http://ui.com**

PHP header code should be like,

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://ui.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Put the below line in angular config.js

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

What I did, never set "*****" as wild character to **$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials**,just mention full domain name from where the ajax code is reside.

Comment: We have a servicestack server (with a known endpoint) and multiple UI servers with unknown endpoints.  We want the UI server users to be able to authenticate against a servicestack service via writing a cookie.  I think adding withCredentials allows this *but* how does the servicestack server allow unknown UI's to access the JSON service responses?

Comment: @CoreyAlix I am looking for a solution to the same issue. How do we allow this with unknown domains? Please post here if you find a solution for this.

Comment: @dev_musings I switched to JSONP.

Comment: @dev-musings, JSONP wasn't the answer because our services aren't all GET services.  We *had* to introduce a whitelist of app servers.  I don't think there is a workaround.

Comment: @CoreyAlix
Due to security perspective, modern browsers reject the responses from unknown/unauthenticated endpoints. 
Use of JSONP is not the solution as it supports only GET methods.
One thing you can do, you build your APIs where those unknown endpoints can be accessed via any open source command line tool and library(CURL/urllib2).
I think it may help you.

Comment: This actually for `Nodejs` too

Answer (score 3):

[PeeHaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/peehaa) is correct in the comments:

> Just fetch the host of the current request and use that instead of the wildcard

That is, do something like:

<s>`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$requestHeaders['Host']);`</s>

Don't do is this way!

This is what you've asked for exactly and it solves the problem. Basically, the equivalent of `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` However, this will create a huge security hole.

Doing this will effectively mean that any site your user enters will be able to do anything on behalf of your user without his consent or notice since you relay the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with whatever host is sent *and* allow this host to transmit the original user's cookie (if it is set in the browser for your API).

Instead, before relaying you should **always** filter the hosts. Implement some kind of whitelist-checking or regexp-checking and only if it passes, relay the `Host` to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: Can't the HOST be spoofed anyways?

Comment: IF you already have the cookie, you can of course spoof the HOST or just put the cookie in your browser.
However, if you do the CORS as suggested you can just trick the user to go to a malicious site in order to impersonate him. The user does not enter their login there and won't even know the site did anything at all. No cookie stealing is necessary at any point.